# If $Y=\mathbb{E}[X\mid\mathcal{B}]$, then $Y(\omega)=\frac{1}{P(A_i)}\int_{A_i}XdP$

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value, conditional-expectation

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$ be a probability space, and $\mathcal{B}\subset \mathcal{A}$ be a sub-$\sigma$-algebra generated by the partition $\{A_1, \ldots, A_n\}$ of $\Omega$, where $P(A_i)>0$, $i=1,\ldots, n$. I want to prove that if
\begin{align}
1)&\int_BYdP= \int_BXdP\quad\forall B\in \mathcal{B} \\
2)&\: Y \:\mbox{is} \: \mathcal{B}-\mbox{measurable}
\end{align}
Then $\forall \omega \in A_i$:
$$Y(\omega)=\frac{1}{P(A_i)}\int_{A_i}XdP$$
I know that $Y=\mathbb{E}[X\mid\mathcal{B}]$, and I also know that
$$\mathbb{E}[X\mid A_i]=\frac{1}{P(A_i)}\int_{A_i}XdP$$
Then all I need to know it that if $\omega \in A_i$, then $\mathbb{E}[X\mid\mathcal{B}](\omega)=\mathbb{E}[X\mid A_i]$ (this would be well-defined since $\omega$ can only be in one $A_i$). But I am not sure how can I conclude this. Can someone help me?

Comment: This is certainly not true for *all* $\omega$, since the conditional expectation is only even defined up to measure zero modifications.

Comment: @nullUser I know that, but anone of the sets I am working with have zero measure

Comment: even still, your theorem will only be true if $P(\{\omega\}) > 0$ for all $\omega$. Knowing $P(A_i) > 0$ for all $i$ is not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Convice yourself that $E[X|]\mathcal{B}]$ must be a linear combination of the functions $\mathbb{1}_{A_1},\ldots,\mathbb{1}_{A_n}$. That is $$ E[X|\mathcal{B}]=a_1\mathbb{1}_{A_1}+\ldots+a_n\mathbb{1}_{A_n}$$ The rest, is like in geometry or linear algebra, find the Fourier coefficients $c_j$ noticing that $E[\mathbb{1}_{A_j}\mathbb{1}_{A_i}]=0$ for $j\neq i$ (since the $A_j$'s form a partition, $\mathbb{1}_{A_j}\mathbb{1}_{A_i}=\mathbb{1}_{A_j\cap A_i}=0$ if $j\neq i$).

For example:
$$E[X\mathbb{1}_{A_1}]=E\big[E[X|\mathcal{B}]\mathbb{1}_{A_1}\big]=\sum^n_{j=1}c_jE[\mathbb{1}_{A_j}\mathbb{1}_{A_1}]=c_1 P[A_1]$$
so $c_1=\frac{1}{P[A_1]}E[X\mathbb{1}_{A_1}]$

I hope this helps you finish the problem. Let me know if you still have some questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am also interested in proving the backwards implication: if $Y(\omega)=\frac{1}{P(A_i)}\int_{A_i}XdP$ when $\omega \in A_i$, then $Y$ satisfies conditions 1) and 2). Do you have any hints for this?

Comment: Right of the bat, you may try to estimate $E[Y;A_1\cap A_2]$. I am not sure that this will give you that $A_i\cap A_2=\emptyset$ $P$-almost surely but that would be my first try. If that does not work, it maybe false and you may have to cook-up some counter example.

Comment: I've finally done it in a different way; writing $Y=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{P(A_i)}\mathbb{E}[X\textbf{1}_{A_i}]\textbf{1}_{A_i}$ and writing any $B$ as a union of the $A_i$. Then it is clear that $\int_{B}YdP=\int_{A_{i_1}\cup\ldots\cup A_{i_k}}YdP=\int_{A_{i_1}\cup\ldots\cup A_{i_k}}XdP=\int_{B}XdP$. Thank you very much for your help, I really appreciate it